# Current GUI options for Pygame

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, pygame

I'm looking for a good GUI library for Pygame (Python 3.x), but I cannot find one that has been maintained. I've looked at a few, including Pgu, which I liked, but couldn't find a maintained, updated version. I don't want anything to simple, which I could wrap myself if I needed to, but something less complicated than Ocemp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a big fan of PyQt, and it looks like [it works with pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869589/which-python-user-interface-library-can-i-use-for-2d-games).

That answer is old, Qt is close to releasing version 5.2 and Qt 5 includes a new way of designing UIs with a new language called QML.  There's also Qt3d support.  See, for instance, [the powerful Monkey God](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt3d-1.0/quick3d-monkeygod.html)!

Answer (score 2):

I think the newest one was https://launchpad.net/simplegc , which started from a Google Summer of Code.

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking around for a GUI library too. Yet I am learning so a 2013-updated library is not as critical for me, but I've been looking at various code.

You may want to try this, it is the newest (November 2013!)

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SimpleGUICS2Pygame/

Here's another one:

http://www.pygame.org/project-MenuSystem-2031-.html

It was updated as recently as November 2012, so not in the last year, but late in 2012.

Here's a third try. 
http://florian-berger.de/en/software/planes

You may have seen these already.